# Copy a row of data once column A matches a USERFORM textbox

Tags: excel, vba

Been searching around and got a bit confused.

I have a sheet (herein called "ModelSpec") filled with data of TVs with a header that starts at A5:Z5 (Example Header Title is "Part Number", "Brand", "Size", "Resolutions"...etc). Some are with data, some are blank cells.

I'd created some USERFORM to allow user to select how they want to search for their Model Specification.
What I'm trying to do now is to pick up a data ("Part Number") located in the USERFORM textbox that the user selected and do a search in the "ModelSpec" sheet for the Part Number (located in Column A6:A?). The number of rows of data may change and I guess we need a FOR loop to stop at empty rows.

Once found, the entire row will be copied and paste value only on A1:Z1 of the same ModelSpec sheet.
So basically I'm currently working on Private Sub within the FORMS and not MODULES.

From there I have another code to extract the details to a form else where.

Please help this confused man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a starting point for you, and has all the elements you'd need to do what you are asking.

**What's Happening:**

- Click event on the userForm launches this code
- Get the last row of the sheet containing data
- Loop through all rows
- Compare the value of txtPartNumber to the value in Column A of the current row in the loop.
- If a match is found, display message confirming and copy the row being searched to row 1 of the same sheet.
- If no match found, display message.

**notes:**

- There is no handling of user input error.  No upper case to lower case, or dropdown box limiting the user's choices.  A good thing to do (in another question) would be to create a dynamic drop down or comboBox, that is populated by already existing part numbers, limiting the user input error.
- If there is more than one match on the page, it will loop through all of the rows and copy the match to row 1. Then copy over row 1 with any match found after that, so the LAST one will be the only one you see. If you want it to only match the FIRST, then include an End statement right after copying the search row to row 1.  I'm assuming your search column has unique IDs / part numbers.

**Code:**

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()

Dim lastRow As Long, lCol As Long, lRow As Long
Dim sName As String

    sName = "ModelSpec"

    lastRow = Sheets(sName).Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row

    For lRow = 6 To lastRow
        'Check to see if A(lRow) = TextBox.  Exact match required
        If Sheets(sName).Cells(lRow, "A").Text = txtPartNumber.Text Then
            MsgBox("Match Found for Part #: " & txtPartNumber.Text)
            For lCol = 1 To 26      'Loop through columns A-Z, Copy lRow to Row 1
                Sheets(sName).Cells(1, lCol) = Sheets(sName).Cells(lRow, lCol)
            Next lCol
        Else
            MsgBox("No match found for Part #: " & txtPartNumber.Text)
        End If
    Next lRow

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks peege. Spot on what I'm after. Works like magic now. Thanks for the comments and suggestions too. I'd actually had the error handling controls in my userform and the textbox text has already been limited with none-error data. Had removed the MsgBox and leave it to work as a hidden command.